# Issue with type declaration

Tags: typescript, type-declaration

I'm sure I got line 2 here all wrong, can anyone take a look at this code snippet to see what could be improved?

```js
export default async function Home() {
  let todoTasks: { id: string; todoTask: string }[] = [];
  const todoTasksIter = tableClient.listEntities();
  let i = 1;
  for await (const entity of todoTasksIter) {
    i++;
    todoTasks.push({ id: entity.rowKey!, todoTask: entity.todo as string });
  }
}
```

Comment: There's an issue with the increment of the variable i. It seems like you are incrementing i before pushing the task to the todoTasks array, so the first task will have id as 2, the second as 3, and so on. If you want to start with id as 1, you should increment i after pushing the task.

Comment: thanks im currently not using the i variable for anything mainly wondering about the type declaration, appriciate the fast response though!

Comment: Please show what `tableClient.listEntities()` is.

Comment: @ChrisHamilton just a client for connecting to azure table storage. Not relevant here as my questions is mainly about the type declaration in TypeScript.

Comment: @RobertPetersson it's very relevant, the type declaration depends on what type that function returns. Are you getting some sort of error?